# Is there any solution to redirect rtmp input to another media server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, streaming, rtmp

First, sorry for my improper English.
I know that English is useful but not necessary at programmer's protocol.

Here is my question.
Is there any solution to redirect rtmp input to another media server?

I just use aws medialive and notify that domain is not static.

AWS MediaLive
Cloud environment.
Every single instance has IP address.
Every channel must be managed channel pool service.
Always mediaLive channel status is running.

I need to unify rtmp input destination URL's domain for streamers.

ex) `rtmp://subdomain.domain.com/input/${streamer_id_or_secret_key}`

Streamer call `rtmp://subdomain.domain.com/input/user_1`

Server request available AWS meidalive channel `rtmp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/input` and redirect? or relay? stream.